# Is there a way to stop the theme and especially plugins listed?

Tags: plugins, themes

The below site list the plugins and themes used in a wordpress blog. Is there a way to stop the theme and especially plugins listed?

http://whatwpthemeisthat.com/

Comment: Do leave a comment for downvote.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd guess it was because of 1) the length of the question, 2) the apparent lack of research, and 3) the fact that similar questions litter the web.

Comment: Hover over the down arrow and read its title. That’s the explanation. No need to repeat it in a comment.

Comment: @toscho I did lot of research before posting this question. Also my question seems to be clear as to what I am trying to achieve. I believe the length of question should not matter as I can write 100 lines which can have no meaning. If as a starter for wordpress I have this question in mind should I not post in this forum? How this question can be framed in a better way so that I don’t get any downvote?

Comment: Document your research efforts, explain what didn’t work, so we don’t have to repeat your work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to stop the theme and especially plugins listed?

No, very doubtful that you can ever pull that off unless the site maintainers will honor requests not to list particular themes or plugins.

What you are asking is the equivalent of "Is there any way to disguise the make and model of a car?" Not really. You'd have to replace pretty much everything. I can look at site and tell you the same information in 30-60 seconds. The information is all pretty much in the source of the page. To prevent sites like that, or people like me :), from fingerprinting your site you would have to jump through many, many enormous hoops of flaming acid, and would probably take a rebuild of significant parts of the WordPress Core.

I suppose you could blacklist requests from that domain but that may be a server level task depending on how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am newbie and did lot of search but it always better to have expert opinion so thought to post this question."I can look at site and tell you the same information in 30-60 seconds". Can you please tell which plugins are used in this site http://arstechnica.com/

Comment: I can give you the same information as the site you listed: They aren't using plugins or, more likely, the plugins are custom and don't expose themselves readily. My site specific plugins do not register, nor do my MU-Plugins. I checked a couple of sites.

Comment: @Santosh There is definitely a way to stop the site you mentioned to not list the theme and plugins for a wp site ... like you can check the same site cannot list the theme and plugins for http://techcrunch.com/ , it is not able to extract info from techcrunch. But i dont know how this is done ... Just letting you know it can be done :)

Comment: @MarutiMohanty Thanks. Even i know this can be done. But how is a big question now.